# ¿ Problema con petición OPTIONS cuando hago una petición POST en AJAX con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hola tengo un problema con una petición post AJAX en jquery, ya que me genera dos peticiones una POST y otra OPTIONS, no sé si esto será un problema a la larga o que el API se confunda.

¿ Porque sale siempre esa petición OPTIONS ? ¿ Se podría quitar ?

```
 $.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/newClient/", {
    data: JSON.stringify(validData),
}, function (response) {
    var r = JSON.parse(response);
    if (r.status != 200) {
        $('#err').html(r.content).css('color', 'red');
    }
    else {
        $('#err').remove();
    }
})
```

El API esta en Django y estas son las cabecera de respuesta que me genera.

Cabecera POST

[image: POST]

Cabecera OPTIONS

[image: OPTIONS]

Comment: Mira este artículo en español de MDN sobre [control de acceso HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). Creo que ahí podrás encontrar el motivo por el que se añade una petición OPTIONS en tu caso.

Comment: Lo he visto, pero no dice nada sobre si es obligatorio hacerlo o simplemente si se puede quitar. El problema es que hace dos peticiones al API que pasa si tienes un numero limitado de peticiones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto se llama una petición `preflighted` y no es un problema es una solicitud que se realiza el navegador a tu servidor para comprobar que la solicitud que intentas hacer es segura.

> Para mas información lee este apartado
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Solicitudes_Verificadas

## Por qué?

La razón por que se envía esta solicitud es porque estas intentando realizar una petición `POST` a otro dominio ([`CORS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)) en tu caso `127.0.0.1:8000`.

Por lo tanto chrome realiza una solicitud `preflighted` para comprobar que `http://127.0.0.1:8000` permite la solicitud a este dominio.

## Resumen

Ya que esta solicitud se realiza por el navegador por motivos de seguridad,
esta mas que justificada.
Y no altera la solicitud original los datos que recibas en la respuesta sera la que esperas.